# How can I find the associated event to the notification counter next to a calendar in Apple's Calendar app?

Tags: notifications, calendar, ical

I have the following notification counter in Apple's Calendar app:

[image: Notification counter in Calendar]

What does this "**1**" on the dark oval stand for? If it refers to an event, how do I find this event? And then how can I get rid of the counter notification (i.e. getting rid of the "**1**" on the dark oval)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification should appear on the Calendar's top bar

[image]

from where you can open it & OK.

[image]